# Create A Blank Html Space On The Fly Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I create a blank space on the fly using javascript? 
The following is not working for me..

```
var blank = document.createElement("&nbsp;");
div.appendChild(blank);
```

Comment: Some options [described here](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=17278)

Comment: @MattBall that's not helpful. The OP clearly didn't understand that `&nbsp;` isn't a tag, indicating a novice level of skill and understanding. Try to be helpful, not degrading - explain why what they are doing isn't correct.

Comment: @dudewad please do realize that comment is more than 5 years old.

Comment: Yep, but my response still stands. This is how people learn good SO conduct; its how I learned it and its why SO is so great. Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really just want to append a space character, use the following:

```
div.innerHTML += ' ';
```

or

```
div.innerHTML += '&nbsp;';
```

for the HTML entity.

Comment: Use innerHTML with care. Please read up on [potential issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190024/is-innerhtml-still-considered-to-be-evil-and-why)

Answer (score 109):

Try using this:

```
myElement.appendChild( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0' ) );
```

If you want/need more spaces, use several `\u00A0` e.g.:

```
myElement.appendChild( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0\u00A0' ) );
```

---

This one:

```
document.createEntityReference('nbsp');
```

doesn't work all browsers, so **avoid it**.

Comment: document.createEntityReference is NOT properly supported by web browsers such as Firefox, IE and Opera. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEntityReference

Comment: Must be picked as the best answer instead

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `document.createTextNode(' ')` I believe.

This can only be used for plain text though, not for entities.

Comment: @Andreas You're right. I've edited my answer to reflect that this can only be used to add straight text, not entities.

Comment: @AlexGamezo That is not quite right. `.createTextNode('\u00A0')` would produce a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML +="!";
```

works (I use exclaimation for immediacy of results, replace with what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

you could do that as follows; but if you want some empty space maybe css would work better (margin, padding, ...)

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"; // (if this doesn't work try " ")
anyElement.appendChild(span); // make sure anyElement actually points to a DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementById("your-button").firstChild.data = '\u00A0';
```

it worked for me ;)

Answer (score -2):

This could help!!

```js
var blank = document.createElement("br");
    /*this creates a br(for a break) element dynamically */
myElement.appendChild(blank);
    /* myElement could be any HTML element like div , 
    span , img etc created dynamically , 
    var myElement = document.createElement("your element") */
```

You could append br as many times you want to get that many blank lines.

Comment: this is not for space but for additional line

Answer (score -2):

```
<body>
<table id="nadis">

</tr>
</table>

</body>

var numarray = ["1.1", "12.20", "151.12", 1000.23,12451.0733];
    var highetlen = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<numarray.length; i++){
        var n = numarray[i].toString();
      var res= n.split(".");
      n = res[0];

      if(highetlen < n.length){
        highetlen = n.length;
      }

    }

    for(var j=0; j<numarray.length; j++){
        var s = numarray[j].toString();
      var res= s.split(".");
      s = res[0];

        if(highetlen > s.length){
      var finallevel = highetlen - s.length;

      var finalhigh = "";
      for(k=0;k<finallevel;k++){
      finalhigh = finalhigh+ '&#160; ';
      }
        numarray[j] = finalhigh + numarray[j];
      }
      var nadiss = document.getElementById("nadis");
      nadiss.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + numarray[j] + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. [A proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) would greatly improve its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.